# Manually set spring security auth remember me

Tags: spring-security

In implementing the apps login,I want to use the spring security to  set who logins,but how to set remember? My UserLogin likes this.

UserDetails usDetails userDetails.loadUserByUsername(u.getAccount()); Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            usDetails, usDetails.getPassword(), usDetails.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);  session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT",SecurityContextHolder.getContext());

But How can I set remember?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your class should wire in the `RememberMeServices` bean being used in your application.

Once the authentication code you listed above executes, you should call the following:

```
rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, authentication);
```

The request passed into the method must have the remember me parameter (default `_spring_security_remember_me`) set to `true` as the call checks the request to make sure remember me was indicated.

RememberMeServices documentation: 
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/RememberMeServices.html

AbstractRememberMeServices source: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/AbstractRememberMeServices.java

The actual implementing class depends on what type of remember me you implemented/indicatd in your application.

Comment: The remember me param is now "remember-me", just for your information.